# Flash Builder 4 BlazeDS Problem

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4, blazeds, builder

Currently, I'm trying to develop a rich internet application using Flash Builder 4 Beta

In Flash builder 4 BlazeDS can be connected directly using Data menu.

However, I face this problem where the program keep asking me to uncomment RDS Servlet, which I have already done so. Does anyone have similar problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you restart BlazeDS after uncommenting it?

Comment: Yes, I already have. I restart glassfish server as well but it still doesn't work. In addition to this even if I have change security to false (no password) FB 4 still ask for password every time I tried to connect to blazeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was caused by using Glassfish v2 where BlazeDS doesn't support it. Anyone who has similar problem try moving to Glassfish v3.